# How to pass a function with parameters in react with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to pass a handleClick to the son so I don't have to do it twice. The code is the following:

Mother:

```
const Mother = () => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<'rooms' | 'questions' | 'notifications'>('rooms')

    const customSectionStyle = 'bg-primary-500 text-white hover:bg-primary-600'

    //handle click
    const handleClick = (href, section) => {
      setSelectedOption(section);
      router.push(href)
    }
    return(
        <>
            <Son onClick={() => handleClick} selectedOption={selectedOption} customSectionStyle={customSectionStyle}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Son:

```
const Son: React.FC<{ selectedOption?: string | '', onClick?: (href: string, section: string) => void | void, customSectionStyle?: string | '' }> = (selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle) => {
    return(
        <>
            <MyComponent onClick={() => {onClick('/','home')}} customStyle={selectedOption === 'rooms' ? customSectionStyle : ''}/>
            <MyComponent onClick={() => {onClick('/','settings')}} customStyle={selectedOption === 'settings' ? customSectionStyle : ''}/>
        //...
        </>
    )
}
```

Basically this sets the background color in case an option is selected or not.
**MyComponent** is a component that takes that props (and/or others) and sets its own content.

This throws the type error *_onClick is not a function*.
I believe I didn't do it properly.. What did I miss, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure about returning two adjacent MyComponent over there?
And I think that you miss the curly braces when getting the props in the son component definition =

> ({ selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle })

Comment: Oh yea man the code is much bigger so I did a little example.. I missed the fragment! Thanks

Comment: Now there is **another problem**! in the Son component the **onClick** says *Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)* and the console throws the following warning: *Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.* What should I do?

Comment: What I mean is that the **useState** doesn't work

Comment: Try to change the name of the prop that you're passing to Son Component from onClick toa another name "blabbal" for example because I think the source of your problem is that keyword

Comment: I changed the name into **handleClick** but it wasn't working too. I had also to change the **handleClick={() => handleClick}** into **handleClick={handleClick}** and now it works the way I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
const Son: React.FC<{ selectedOption?: string | '', onClick?: (href: string, section: string) => void | void, customSectionStyle?: string | '' }> = (selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle)
```

Replace with

```
const Son: React.FC<{ selectedOption?: string, onClick?: (href: string, section: string) => void, customSectionStyle?: string }> = ({ selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle })
```

Answer (score 1):

Son Will be called with all props that you've to Destructur it or directly read from props

(selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle)  should be ({selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle})

```js
const Son: React.FC<{ selectedOption?: string | '', onClick?: (href: string, section: string) => void | void, customSectionStyle?: string | '' }> = ({selectedOption, onClick, customSectionStyle}) => {
    return(
        <MyComponent onClick={() => {onClick('/','home')}} customStyle={selectedOption === 'rooms' ? customSectionStyle : ''}/>
        <MyComponent onClick={() => {onClick('/','settings')}} customStyle={selectedOption === 'settings' ? customSectionStyle : ''}/>
        //...
    )
}
```